# How to filter, order and query LTree in EF Core

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0, ltree

As already described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77507707/ef-core-ltreecolumn-matcheslquery-throws-exception) I'm struggling with LTree and the right way to query. I'm using an object, containing LTree as a column on one of my tables. This is how the object looks like:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class MyObject
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public LTree LTreeColumn {get;set;}
    ....
}
```

If it is not possible to use the [LTree-functions](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/api/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.LTree.html) as expected, it's not nice, but also not worst case. But it would be nice, if there is a way, to order and filter a collection, based on LTree.

`OrderBy` fails, because of missing `IComparable` implementation. Is there an alternative approach? And how to find the first item on the "tree" given a specific sub-path?

Let's say, I have a structure beginning with `Top`, followed by `Top.One`, `Top.Two`, `Top.One.One` and so on...

Now I want to find the highest object, beginning with `Top` in a collection. How can I do this on database and in memory?

And in general (based on a common sub-path) how to evaluate `<` or `>` correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I figured out so far... If someone knows better or more I highly appreciate another answer.

All LTree-functions will be translated to queries. LTree holds NLevel as a property, which can be used for ordering (as query, not in memory):

`var ordered = _dbContext.MyObjects.OrderBy(e=>e.LTreeColumn.NLevel)`

Highest in specific path:

```
var highest = _dbContext.MyObjects.Where(e=>e.LTreeColumn.MatchesLQuery("Top.*"))
    .OrderBy(e=>e.LTreeColumn.NLevel).First();
```

If I need the level of LTreeColumn in an in-memory collection I use these extension-methods:

```
public static int GetLTreeLevel(this string lTree)
    => lTree.Split('.').Length;

public static int GetLTreeLevel(this LTree lTree)
    => lTree.ToString().GetLTreeLevel();
```

Compare the level of two instances of MyObject:

```
var isHigher = first.LTreeColumn.GetLTreeLevel() < second.LTreeColumn.GetLTreeLevel();
```